# Looking at an incoming page and determing if a form is being passed

Tags: forms, coldfusion, struct, cfml

I need to determine whether or not a page is passing a form to our internal site. We need to redirect if the page comes from an outside domain.

A coworker came up with this code:

```
<cfif isDefined("form")>
  <cfif not findnocase("our_domain", http_referer)>
    <cflocation url="redirect_link">
  </cfif>
</cfif>
```

I don't think he is using `isDefined()` properly because `isDefined()` looks for a variable. We need to look for the form itself. I've also looked into `structKeyExists()`, but again, this looks for variables within the form. How can I look for the form itself?

Comment: You can't depend on cgi.http_referer containing your domain name - it might be blank even if the user came from your site, can be changed by client software, and - because you're doing a generic find check (rather than doing an equality check) can be easily spoofed by other websites too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two ways. You can check CGI.REQUEST_METHOD to check for whether a POST is being sent.

You can also check `structKeyExists(form,"fieldNames")` which will only be the case when a form has actually been submitted.

Although not in the question, I'd also avoid referencing http_referer without a scope. Use CGI.http_referer as it's easier to read. You could also combine the test for FORM and the external referer into one statement:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form,"fieldNames") AND NOT findnocase("our_domain", CGI.http_referer)>
   <cflocation url="redirect_link">
</cfif>
```

Also, you know that the redirect won't carry any of the form fields over with it? I'm guessing that's what you want, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it would be something like this. I will implement something similar to what you posted above.

Comment: I like the completeness of this answer but two minor details are off.  1. Using StructKeyExists is the preferred method over using IsDefined() for performance.  StructKeyExists is evaluated faster.  2. You should not use FindNoCase as a boolean because it doesn't return a true boolean, it's an index value (numeric).  You should check it using ListFindNoCase(... ) GT 0 or set the return value to a variable and use it, #varname# GT 0.

Comment: You can also use !structIsEmpyty( form ) AND NOT findnocase("our_domain", CGI.http_referer)

Answer (score 2):

`isDefined()` actually looks in all scopes, variables, form, url, application, session, client if they all exists, but in this case you want to use use `structKeyExists` by doing `structKeyExists(form,'fieldnames')` You can also check for a specific form field.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form,'fieldnames')>
    <cfif not findnocase("our_domain", cgi.http_referer)> // scope http_referer
        <cflocation url="redirect_link" addtoken="false">
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

If you don't scope cgi.http_referer the user could pass in a url variable called http_referer to spoof the page. Doesn't appear it would make a difference in this scenario, but still a good practice to follow.

Comment: The CGI variable is client-provided so entirely spoofable anyway. (It's also blanked by some security software.)

Answer (score 0):

The way he's using isDefined on the form scope will always pass, because the form scope is a predefined CF scope for all pages.  You would need to check if a specific variable in a form is being used.  It's even more helpful if you know what fields will be passed from the form (in other words, if the same form is always expected on this landing page).  If all of these are true, you can use the fieldnames form value, which is a value appended to ColdFusion forms when a form is submitted.

```
<cfif NOT structKeyExists(form, 'fieldnames') AND NOT findnocase("our_domain", http_referer)>
     <cflocation url="someurl" addtoken="false" />
<cfelse>
     <!--- Page Processing actions go here --->
</cfif>
```

If you know what the field names are, then you can refine the conditional to check for the fieldname values are as well and pass or fail it that way; though I would likely use a flag and check the conditionals pro grammatically in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the referred domain is always a problem as it is so easy to spoof.
One method you can use is to pass a variable in the form that gets generated by your site, so can only exist if the form was submitted by your site.
Fot example.
Create a uuid each time page is loaded
Store it in visitors session and also put it in the form.

When form is submitted, compare form.uuid with session.page.uuid, only if they match was form submitted from your own site.